# How to get SaveChanges method rolling back only failed records in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

I have a scenario where I want to insert hundreds of records to a database table and I want to insert them as chunks(e.g 10 records) and I need **Entity Framework** only to rollback failed records and to return the failed records to me?

My first question How can I achieve that?

My second question is there a good practice for inserting large number of records irrespective of the scenario I have mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

```
StatelessSession session = factory.openStatelessSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for(int i = 0; i < resultItems.size(); i++) {
   try
   {
       Customer cust = new Customer(resultItems.get(i));   
       Long id = session.save(cust); // get the generated id
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    //track your exceptional customer here
    System.out.println("customer not added ="+resultItems.get(i).custorName)
   }

    if(i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```